# how to automatically retrieve a csv file from an email and dump contents into an oracle database table

Tags: email, oracle11g, oracle10g, attachment, google-analytics-firebase

Good Day!

I have set up an automated daily email coming from Google Analytics and need to extract the CSV file contents and dump them into an Oracle database table on a daily basis...

I'm almost positive that this is possible, but not sure how to go about setting this up?

If someone has already set this up, could you share the steps?

thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's a [PL/SQL Mail Client API](http://plsqlmailclient.sourceforge.net/) available on source forge.  It appears to be a PL/SQL wrapper for the Java Mail API, though I've never used either one.